# Fill a queue with address instead of numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I was wondering if you can push an address onto a queue instead of its contents. For example I have a 2d array and I'm moving around it. I want to keep track of the spots I've been in and I don't necessarily care about the contents of those spots.

Comment: Yes, you can push an address into a queue, instead of its contents. You just have to declare the queue as containing pointers to whatever the addresses point to. HTH. HAND.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to declare queue as queue of pointers, for example " int* " or whatever type you are using. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;


int main() { ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);

    int a = 3, b = 4, c = 25;

    queue <int*> q;
    q.push(&a);
    q.push(&b);
    q.push(&c);

    while (!q.empty()) {
        cout << *q.front() << "->"; // printing values
        cout << q.front() << ' '; // printing adresses
        q.pop();
    }

    cout << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```